# Loading UIWebView from a slideview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIViewController` that looks similar to this.

[image]

On the left side is a `TableViewController` with cells and on the right side is a `UIWebView`. Upon clicking the cell I would like to load a unique URL depending on which cell was clicked.

For some reason when I click the cell, a request is never sent to the `UIWebView` to load the url. Both the `UIWebView` and the `UITableViewDelegate` are in the same `UIViewController`.

Here is my sample code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 NSMutableURLRequest *request;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com/"]];
    }

    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Why does this not work? Both the `UIWebView` and the `UITableView` are `IBOutlets` in the `viewController`. The click is getting recognized and this `webView` load request works when put in the `viewDidLoad` function but when the same code is used on click nothing happens.

I am using this github api if it helps you https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Thanks for the help,
Mike

Comment: Did you try implementing [`webView:didFailLoadWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and checking if it returns an error. You could also set a breakpoint and step through the method to make sure you didn't miss something else (like `webView` being nil for no good reason). Thats all I can really think of what what you've given though.

Comment: hey axiixc, I put a break point on the first line of didFailLoadWithError but it is never getting called. Also when stepping through, I can see that request is getting populated correctly and webView is not nil when data is being passed to it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was trying to make the UIWebView load the request in a controller which was not the delegate (in this case the side view). Instead, I set the UIWebView as a property in the side view and had the uiWebViewController.webView.loadRequest:request and it worked.

Thanks for everyones suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

after `[webView loadRequest:request];` line just add this line ...

```
[webView reload];
```

Refer this document... [UIWebView_Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**For ex:**

```
[webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"]]];
[webView reload];
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed. `loadRequest:` will kick off the page load immediately.

Comment: ya i know dude.. but some time its not work and for that if we refresh the uiwebview then it will work... like retain procedure ... :)

Comment: Hey Paras, no luck on forcing a reload.

Comment: you give delegate to self to UIWebView?? and put UIWebViewDelegate in .h file??

Comment: @interface FFWebViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

Comment: see just try with add this webView.delegate = self; in viewDidLoad and let me know..

Comment: check whether the Webview is connected properly

Comment: which version you used now??

Comment: before some time it happens with me and after that in viewDidDissappear emthod i write this line        [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]]; and in viewWillAppear i set new URL.. then its worked.. try something with this line... first assign blank url to webview and then assign ur url...

Comment: Varun, the webview is connected correctly using the CTR + Click-drag and assigning both this as the delegate as well as connecting the uiWebView to the UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Are you Able to Load `WebView` ? If Yes than :

First you need to check in xib file that connections are given proper or not about the Referencing Outlets & Delegate.

Secondly if connections are proper than do the Following:
You have taken `NSMutableURLRequest` take `NSURLRequest` instead of that

See this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSURLRequest *request;
   if (indexPath.row == 0)
   {
      request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
   }
   else if (indexPath.row == 1)
   {
      request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]];
   }
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Hope this will Help.

Comment: Hey Mayur, both the delegate and datasource are wired up correctly in the storyboard view. I changed the NSMutable to a regular NSURLRequest but with no luck.

Comment: @MikeBaglio Sorry that solution not worked for you but i want to ask about on click WebView Appears or not ?